# Spotipy: How to pass the auth token to the client

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to build an app using the spotipy python library to access the spotify api.

My oauth code looks like this and it seems to work except for initialising the client with the right auth parameter.

```
self.sp_auth=spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(secrets.sp_auth_id,
                                secrets.sp_auth_pw, secrets.sp_callback_url,
                                scope="playlist-modify-public user-library-read", state=state)
```

...

```
url = self.sp_auth.get_authorize_url()
```

send url to user.
after user said she/he has given permission:
auth code is fetched from webserver and used to generate a token.

```
self.auth_token=self.sp_auth.get_access_token(self.auth_code)
```

self.auth_token then looks like this:

```
{'access_token'  : 'BQD ... qE7K3PBZKB6iZFU3_4p', 
 'token_type'    : 'Bearer',
 'expires_in'    : 3600,
 'refresh_token' : 'AQCOS2Xo ... MK09ry7-a-fl61OwhuO1Q',
 'scope'         : 'playlist-modify-public user-library-read',
 'expires_at'    : 1548247835}
```

then I initialize the spotipy client module like this:

```
self.sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=self.auth_token)
```

then I try the following:

```
playlists = self.sp.current_user_playlists(limit=10)
```

which raises this Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 119, in _internal_call
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists?limit=10&offset=0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 279, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telegram/ext/callbackqueryhandler.py", line 143, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
  File "spotify_playlist_bot_v2.py", line 140, in button_auth_done
    User.data[user_id].msg_start(bot, update)
  File "spotify_playlist_bot_v2.py", line 84, in msg_start
    self.msg_choose_playlist()
  File "spotify_playlist_bot_v2.py", line 90, in msg_choose_playlist
    playlists = self.sp.current_user_playlists(limit=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 355, in current_user_playlists
    return self._get("me/playlists", limit=limit, offset=offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 146, in _get
    return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 124, in _internal_call
    headers=r.headers)
spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists?limit=10&offset=0:
 Only valid bearer authentication supported
```

It looks like I'm not passing the token to the spotipy client correctly. For example `self.sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth="random_bullshit")` gives me the same Exception. I also tried passing the token like this `auth=self.auth_token['access_token']` with the same result. The documentation doesn't say anything about what the auth parameter should be exactly and I'm not really understanding the [source code](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/spotipy/client.py#L72). But I'd say it suggests that `auth=self.auth_token['access_token']` is the right thing to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I already suggested in my last edit `auth=self.auth_token['access_token']` was the right thing I just had a typo in it. Anyway since the Documentation doesn't say a lot about the auth parameter this might help some people.